# Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS takes 30+ seconds to launch and has weird display issues while launching

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, google-chrome

When launching Chrome on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, it takes 30+ seconds to launch properly. It will create a window almost immediately but has weird rendering issues (the window is invisible but if you drag another window across it will create "trails" of the window that was dragged across, like it used to on older versions of windows when something would crash). If I take a screen recording on the laptop it just shows a black screen the whole time until it renders properly. I can still re-size and move the window around while its in this state.

Edit to add: If I open a new window while chrome is still running it opens fine, but if I close Chrome and re-open it, it goes through the whole loading issue.

So far I have tried disabling `GPU Rasterization` in Chrome settings as well as hardware acceleration. If I turn these off Chrome will never render properly. I have also tried checking for updates, un-installing and re-installing Chrome. From what I have read so far it seems like it might be an issue with the Nvidia card/drivers.

I'm running it on a dual-booted Dell XPS-15 1920, with 32 GB ram, i7-12700H, and an Nvidia 3050 Ti mobile.

Anyone have suggestions before I just try re-installing Ubuntu?

[Screen Recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmEsw.jpg)

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWCB7.jpg) of screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue! Solved it by downgrading Nvidia drivers to version 510. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes

Comment: This worked thank you!

For anyone else checking this out I followed the steps [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/r1ofn7/how_do_you_downgrade_nvidia_driver/) 

'sudo apt-get purge '*nvidia*''
'sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510'

They also recommended backing up your system for doing this.

Edit: the mini-Markdown is messing with the code so make sure to check the link for the proper code

Comment: I have the same machine and had the same problem. After several tests, I determined that the "open" version of the Nvidia 525 driver was the underlying issue. Switching to the "proprietary" 525 driver ultimately solved my problem. Versions 510 and 515 (proprietary) worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after upgrading to Jammy 22.04 from Focal 20.04, on Google Chrome 114.

It looks like turning Off 'Use hardware acceleration when available' in Settings --> System, relaunching Google Chrome, then turning On again 'Use hardware acceleration when available', did the trick.

I was already on the same nVidia driver 535 in Focal 20.04. So, something went badly after the Ubuntu upgrade. I believe I forced it to ditch the settings and renew them with the same driver, albeit for a different Ubuntu system software.

Answer (score 1):

I reread your post - sounds like you already tried this....  It had worked for me previously

Have you checked to see if Chrome is using "Use hardware acceleration when available"?  Try disabling that setting the the Chrome settings.

Instructions:
Click the stacked 3 dots on the top right Chrome.
Select "Settings".  Select "System".
Change "Use hardware acceleration when available" slider to off.
Relaunch Chrome.

Comment: Thank you but yeah that was one of the first recommendations I got, it allows me to launch chrome but I still have the issue with Chrome taking 30+ seconds to launch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact same symptoms, and this thread made me realize it was a GPU issue.
When I ran `lspci` it showed that my integrated graphics were being used instead of the Nvidia card.

I used the stock Software & Updates application, went to the Additional Drivers tab and installed the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-530(proprietary,tested).

After I restarted my computer Chrome booted instantly and there have been no further issues.

[sceenshot of Software & Updates application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTwLK.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, if not the exact same issue: I would click Chrome to open it and have to wait 30 sec to get my result. My solution came from this page:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation

From the page:

```
Installing the drivers for generic use (e.g. desktop and gaming)

You can either rely on automatic detection, which will install the driver that is considered the best match for your hardware:

sudo ubuntu-drivers install  # run this cmd and restart!
```

I ran the cmd, restarted, and then Chrome opened in perhaps 2 seconds. Acceptable.

I also tried and failed with these solutions:

1. Turn hardware acceleration on/off in Chrome & restart.
2. Uninstall, reinstall Chrome.
3. upgrade all Ubuntu packages.